# What does "a run of resources mega- project" mean?

Tags: meaning

I'm translating an English text and when I came to this part I couldn't fully understand it. The quote is from an Australian newspaper. (Emphasis mine)

> Woodside had been targeting a final investment decision this year and today’s announcement represents the shelving of Australia’s last chance to continue **a run of resources mega-project** approvals that have seen $200bn of LNG investments approved in the past decade.

What does **"a run of resources mega-project"** mean? Please help me understand it.

Comment: It's poor English - and (without any research) any interpretation will be pure guesswork.

Comment: @TrevorD thanks for the reply. i forgot to mention its of an Australian newspaper. i think this is the reason

Comment: Thanks, but knowing that it's an AU newspaper doesn't help us interpret what the author meant - it's still poor English!  Any interpretation would (in my opinion) be pure guesswork - and hence a mere opinion.  I may be wrong, but I think it needs more context and some research into the subject to even attempt to understand what he meant - and that is way beyond the scope of this forum.  Sorry!

Comment: @hamid Sorry - I lost the last half of my comment. As it is redundant now I have deleted the original.

Comment: I think it means: ".....a run of approvals of resource megaprojects...."   The question is whether the magaprojects referred to include resources other than natural gas.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the paragraph we are asked to interpret is so badly written that we can't answer with certainty without more context.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the "a run of resources mega-projects" means that there has been a series of mega (huge) projects in the field of (natural) resources, such as oil, gas, iron ore, aluminium and so on. This series has now ended with the shelving of whatever project was in Woodside's cross-hairs.

I agree with @TrevorD that the sentence is fairly poor English from a formal point of view but it is certainly journalistic English.

Comment: Unclear whether the megaprojects referred to  include resources other than natural gas.